# My site and properties from external sources

Tags: user-profile, my-site, bcs, database, user-profile-property

We have an on premise SharePoint 2013  farm.

In setting up mysite, we will only retrieve username and picture from AD, all other properies for profiles we need to get from another database that is not a part of SharePoint.

We have more than 2000 users.

I am wondering how to impelement this and about what kind of things\risks I need to consider.

How will the system understand that data from a database row will be mapped to the correct user?

I have given BCS a thought, but an external list will be to large.

Please advice.

Comment: Did you get this working?

Comment: Hi. I will test soon, in one week or two. We just needed to determine if this is doable in the first place. Thanks a lot for your valuable input.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, BCS is what you need to use.  You don't actually need to setup an external list you just need the connections setup.  Here's a link on how to do this in 2010 (similar steps for 2013):  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alimaz/archive/2011/02/20/importing-sharepoint-user-profile-multi-value-properties-using-bcs.aspx